# How to get data from the nested dictionary?

Tags: python

I have a dictionary:

```
 dict1 = {"1111111-1":{"name":"Bill","id":"123"},"2222222-1":{"name":"John","id":"124"}, "3333333-1":{"name":"Ted","id":"125"}, "2222222-2":{"name":"John","id":"126"}}
```

I would like to print only names and id without key value( "1111111-1", "2222222-1" etc.). Finally, I want to make a list of names and id.

Comment: Please show the expected output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this approach:

```
list_names = []
for key, value in dict1.items():
    print(value['name'], value['id'])
    list_names.append(value['name'])

print(list_names)
```

Comment: Thanks, What if I won't have  id for 2222222-1:   dict1 = {"1111111-1":{"name":"Bill","id":"123"},"2222222-1":{"name":"John","id":},

Comment: then you'd get `SyntaxError: invalid syntax`, because defining dictionary key without a value raises this error.

Answer (score 0):

As the output is not defined clearly at the moment, you can take the following steps -

```
list(dict1.values())
```

This will result a list of dictionaries with name and id -

```
[{'name': 'Bill', 'id': '123'}, {'name': 'John', 'id': '124'}, {'name': 'Ted', 'id': '125'}, {'name': 'John', 'id': '126'}]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply do this:

```
print([list(x.values()) for x in dict1.values()])
```

Comment: Can you remove the unvote? I misunderstood the question and now I corrected the answer.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need:

```
names = [v['name'] for k,v in dict1.items()]
ids = [v['id'] for k,v in dict1.items()]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
dict1 = {"1111111-1":{"name":"Bill","id":"123"},"2222222-1":{"name":"John","id":"124"}, "3333333-1":{"name":"Ted","id":"125"}, "2222222-2":{"name":"John","id":"126"}}

names=[]
ids=[]

for value in dict1.values():
    names.append(value["name"])
    ids.append(value["id"])

print(names)
print(ids)
```

Answer (score 0):

First make a dictionary with the names and ids, then the lists you require are easily accessible:

```
name_id_dict = { v['name'] : v['id'] for k,v in dict1.items() }

names = name_id_dict.keys()
ids = name_id_dict.values()
```